# Compare a Column from CSV with a Column in EXL and add the result to my CSV File

Tags: powershell

I want to compare my CSV File with EXL file.

The EXL file has many columns such as USERID and WAVE. My CSV file has just USERID Column.

it should compare my CSV Column USerID with USERID Column in Exl and checks in which wave the user A in CSV has in EXL file and add a wave column in CSV File called "WAVE” and write the wave Number related to USER A in CSV file.

If no name from CSV file is found in EXL file, write in the Column Wave “NOT Found".

I am not sure what I wrote "Read and Get Values from Excel" helps or not but I have no clue how/what to do further.

```
$TXTFile = "C:\A.txt" 
$CSVFile = "C:\B.csv" 
$EXLFIle = "C:\C.xlsx"

#find all CNs in TXT file and list them in CSV File
Select-String -Path $TXTFile  -Pattern 'CN=(.*?),' -AllMatches |
  Select-Object -Expand Matches |
  ForEach-Object { $_.Groups[1].Value } | 
  select @{L="UserID"; E={$_}} |
  Export-CSV $CSVFile -noTypeInformation

# Read and Get Values from Excel 
#Create an instance of Excel.Application and Open Excel file
$ObjExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Workbook = $ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open($EXLFIle)
$Sheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item($SheetName)
$ObjExcel.Visible = $false

#Count max Rows
$RowMax = ($sheet.UsedRange.rows).count

#Declare the starting positions
$rowUserID,$colUserID = 1,2
$rowWave,$colWave = 1,9

for ($i=1; $i -le $RowMax-1; $i++)
{
$UserID = $Sheet.Cells.Item($rowUserID+$i,$colUserID).text
$Wave = $Sheet.Cells.Item($rowWave+$i,$colWave).text

Write-Host ("USERID: "+$UserID)
Write-Host ("Wave: "+$Wave)
}

$objExcel.quit()
```

#### UPDATE

I changed the script in this way, but it does not give me any error or any result. EXL file has 26000 raws. I do not know if it takes too much time or sth is wrong in my script.

```
$TXTFile = "C:\A.txt" 
$CSVFile1 = "C:\A.csv" 
$EXLFile = "C:\B.xlsx"
$Result = "C:\Result.csv" 
$CSVFile2 = "C:\B.csv"

#find all CNs in TXT file and list them in CSV File
Select-String -Path $TXTFile  -Pattern 'CN=(.*?),' -AllMatches |
  Select-Object -Expand Matches |
  ForEach-Object { $_.Groups[1].Value } | 
  select @{L="UserID"; E={$_}} |
  Export-CSV $CSVFile1 -noTypeInformation

########################################################################
# Convert EXL file  to CSV File
$excelwb = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$workbook = $excelwb.Workbooks.Open($EXLFile)
$workbook.SaveAs($CSVFile2,6)
$workbook.Close($false)
$ExcelWB.quit()
$csv = Import-Csv $CSVFile2 -Delimiter ";"
########################################################################
# We Compare File2 with File1
$file2 = import-csv $CSVFile2         
$file1 = import-csv $CSVFile1         

$Output = @()

    ForEach ($a in $file2)
    {
        $Match = $file1 | where {$_."User ID" -eq $a.UserID}
        If($Match)
        {
           $Output += New-Object PsObject -Property @{"User ID" =$a.UserID;column9 =$Match.column9}
        }
        else
        {
        $Output += New-Object PsObject -Property @{"User ID" =$a.UserID;column9 ="NA"}
        }
    }
$Output | Export-Csv $Result
```

Comment: So what happens if you run your code?

Comment: It just reads UserID and Wave Column in excell. I am unable to compare and add a column with numbers...

Comment: Does your script hang, or exit without any results? Have you looked at the tables before you start comparison? Just put `$file1` on its own line after importing. What's printed on the console, does it look right? Same for `$file2`. If the tables are big, just show the first lines: `$file1 | select -First 10`

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your Tip. after a week I found out by "select -First 10" that $file2 cannot be read. it shows me empty and now I have to discover why my CSV file is not readable somehow...

Answer (score 0):

Don't export the user IDs in the beginning, just store them in an array, say `$UserList` and for output create an empty array `$out=@()`. Now inside your loop, you can do comparison and add the user and wave information to the `$out`:

```
if($UserList -contains $UserID) {
    $w = $Wave
} else {
    $w = "NOT Found"
}
$out += new-object PSObject -Property @{"UserID"=$UserID; "Wave"=$w}
```

In the end export results:

```
$out | Export-Csv $CSVFile
```

Comment: Thanks. I made a change to my script. Could you please check what is wrong by my script?